# AppDelegate unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am working on a project and i am implementing this SDK https://docs.drivequant.com/trip-analysis/ios/get-started and I am implementing it in appdelegeate.m

here how I import the module

```
@import DriveKitCoreModule;
@import DriveKitTripAnalysisModule;
```

and here how I initialise it

```
[[DriveKit shared] initialize];
  [[DriveKit shared] setApiKeyWithKey: @""];
  [[DriveKit shared] setUserIdWithUserId: @""];
  [[DriveKit shared] enableLoggingWithShowInConsole:YES];
 
  [[DriveKitTripAnalysis shared] initializeWithTripListener: self appLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

but I always get this warning with initializeWithTripListener

[image]

and after running I got this error

[image]

does anyone know why I am getting this error? and how to fix it?

Comment: You are missing this part `Make the AppDelegate class implement TripListener protocol` which explain the warning and the compiler error...

Comment: do you have any example of doing this ? and thank you

Comment: Your code is Objective-C. You should probably delete the `swift` tag on your question, as those who only know Swift will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) for a description of how you declare that an Objective-C class conforms to a protocol. (Specifically the section titled "Conforming to Protocols".)

Looking at the readme for the framework you are using, it says:

> Make the AppDelegate class implement TripListener protocol. This protocol contains 6 methods to implement:

```
func tripPoint(tripPoint: TripPoint) {
}
func tripStarted(startMode: StartMode) {
}
func tripCancelled(cancelTrip: CancelTrip) {
}
func tripFinished(post: PostGeneric, response: PostGenericResponse) {
}
func tripSavedForRepost(){
}
func beaconDetected(){
}
func significantLocationChangeDetected(location: CLLocation){
}
func sdkStateChanged(state: State){
}
```

So you will need to add implementations for those 6 methods to your app delegate. (Those method declarations are in Swift. If you're writing your app delegate in Objective-C you'll need to find the Objective-C function prototypes.)